# "no data exchange required"

Tags: php, magento, web, quickbooks, qbxml

I am new to quickbook and my client wants to sync his Magento orders with QuickBooks. He uses QuickBooks Enterprises desktop edition to sync the orders. We are using PHP devkit web connector and trying sample example given in the doc to add customer.

For the first time the add customer example worked fine but after that when I tried to add another customer, I got 'Data Exchange Required' message in quick web connector and the user was not added to quickbook.

Please help me to solve it and guide me how to add the Magento order to quickbook and customers. Below is the code I was using:

```
    <?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    ini_set('display_errors', true);

    if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')){
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    }

    require_once '../QuickBooks.php';

    $user = 'quickbooks';
    $pass = 'password';

    $map = array(
        QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER => array( '_quickbooks_customer_add_request', '_quickbooks_customer_add_response' ),
        QUICKBOOKS_ADD_INVOICE => array( '_quickbooks_invoice_add_request', '_quickbooks_invoice_add_response' )
        );

    $errmap = array();
    $hooks = array();

    $log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_DEVELOP;        

    $dsn = 'mysql://root:root@localhost/quickbooks_server';

    if (!QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn))
    {
        QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($dsn);
        QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser($dsn, $user, $pass);

        $primary_key_of_your_customer = 5;
        $Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
        $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, $primary_key_of_your_customer);
        $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_INVOICE, $primary_key_of_your_customer);
    }

    $Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($dsn, $map, $errmap, $hooks, $log_level, $soapserver, QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options, $handler_options, $driver_options, $callback_options);
    $response = $Server->handle(true, true);

    function _quickbooks_customer_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
    {

        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
            <QBXML>
                <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                    <CustomerAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                        <CustomerAdd>
                            <Name>Muralidhar, LLC (' . mt_rand() . ')</Name>
                            <CompanyName>Muralidhar, LLC</CompanyName>
                            <FirstName>Muralidhar</FirstName>
                            <LastName>Jampa</LastName>
                            <BillAddress>
                                <Addr1>Muralidhar, LLC</Addr1>
                                <Addr2>134 Stonemill Road</Addr2>
                                <City>NewYork</City>
                                <State>NY</State>
                                <PostalCode>06268</PostalCode>
                                <Country>United States</Country>
                            </BillAddress>
                            <Phone>860-634-1602</Phone>
                            <AltPhone>860-429-0021</AltPhone>
                            <Fax>860-429-5183</Fax>
                            <Email>murarimaniram@gmail.com</Email>
                            <Contact>Muralidhar Jampa</Contact>
                        </CustomerAdd>
                    </CustomerAddRq>
                </QBXMLMsgsRq>
            </QBXML>';

        return $xml;
    }


    function _quickbooks_customer_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
    {
        return; 
    }

    function _quickbooks_invoice_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
    {

        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
                <QBXML>
                  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                    <InvoiceAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                      <InvoiceAdd>
                        <CustomerRef>
                          <FullName>Muralidhar Jampa</FullName>
                        </CustomerRef>
                        <TxnDate>2014-04-14</TxnDate>
                        <RefNumber>9869</RefNumber>
                        <BillAddress>
                          <Addr1>56 Cowles Road</Addr1>
                          <City>Willington</City>
                          <State>CT</State>
                          <PostalCode>06279</PostalCode>
                          <Country>United States</Country>
                        </BillAddress>
                        <PONumber></PONumber>
                        <Memo></Memo>

                        <InvoiceLineAdd>
                          <ItemRef>
                            <FullName>Test Item</FullName>
                          </ItemRef>
                          <Desc>Item 1 Description Goes Here</Desc>
                          <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                          <Rate>295</Rate>
                        </InvoiceLineAdd>

                        <InvoiceLineAdd>
                          <ItemRef>
                            <FullName>Test Item</FullName>
                          </ItemRef>
                          <Desc>Item 2 Description Goes Here</Desc>
                          <Quantity>3</Quantity>
                          <Rate>25</Rate>
                        </InvoiceLineAdd>

                      </InvoiceAdd>
                    </InvoiceAddRq>
                  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                </QBXML>';

        return $xml;
    }


    function _quickbooks_invoice_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
    {
        return; 
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the comments in the example file, you'll find this comment:

```
    // IMPORTANT NOTE: This particular example of queueing something up will 
    //  only ever happen *once* when these scripts are first run/used. After 
    //  this initial test, you MUST do your queueing in another script. DO NOT 
    //  DO YOUR OWN QUEUEING IN THIS FILE! See 
    //  docs/example_web_connector_queueing.php for more details and examples 
    //  of queueing things up.
```

And a link to this page:

- http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_php_consolibyte#the_web_connector_keeps_telling_me_no_data_exchange_required__what_does_that_mean

Which says:

> There's no data to exchange. There's nothing to do. The Web Connector
>   and this framework work using a 'queue' concept. Once the queue is
>   empty, there's nothing else to do, and you'll get that message. If you
>   add something to the queue, then it will process those items until
>   there's nothing left to do, and then you'll get the “No Data
>   Exchange…” message again.
>
> So, for instance, say you want to build a process whereby every time a
>   customer is created within your store, the customer gets created in
>   QuickBooks. You'd then want to set up a process where when that
>   customer is created within your store, you queue up a request to add
>   the customer to QuickBooks.
>
> You do your queueing using the QuickBooks_Queue class, and the
>   →enqueue() method.

So essentially the problem is *you haven't told it to do anything*. The example only adds ONE customer to QuickBooks.

If you want to add more customers, you need to *queue something up* so that it tries to do that.

When you queue something up, note that you *must do that somewhere else*. DO NOT QUEUE STUFF UP IN THIS FILE (just like the comments above say).

So somewhere else in your app, you probably have some code like this for when you add a new customer to your app database:

```
// end-user submitted a form, let's save the customer to our database
if ($_POST['customer_name'])
{
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_customer_table ( ... ) VALUES ( ... )");
}
```

You should modify your app code to then look something like this:

```
// end-user submitted a form, let's save the customer to our database
if ($_POST['customer_name'])
{
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_customer_table ( ... ) VALUES ( ... )");

  // ... and queue them up to be added to QB
  $primary_key_of_your_customer = mysql_insert_id();
  $Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
  $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, $primary_key_of_your_customer);
}
```

As a side note, note that anything in this block:

```
if (!QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn))
{
```

Only runs ONCE. So don't do anything in this block - it won't ever run again.

Comment: Hi Keith, 

Thanks for the reply. here the problem when i try to add another customer in the same way 
$primary_key_of_your_customer = 6;
        $Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
        $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, $primary_key_of_your_customer);
        $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_INVOICE, $primary_key_of_your_customer);

i was getting the error “no data exchange required” message,  first time it worked fine, but second i try to another customer in the same way was getting the “no data exchange required” and user was not added to the quickbook

Thanks,
murali

Comment: I revised the answer to contain a bit more detail. DO NOT queue stuff up in this file. Queue stuff up somewhere else. Anything in that block of code ONLY RUNS ONCE so changing stuff in that block will not make any difference. Queue stuff up in your app.

Comment: Hi Keith, Thanks for the reply. it was working, can you help how to check the a customer / order already exits in the quickbook desktop or not. if not exits then to add the that customer / order to the quickbook, please give me example to do it
thanks,
murali